# sed: perform substitution in back reference

Tags: regex, sed

I'm using the follwing line to produce part of an HTML list:

```
sed -r 's|(.*dn=([^&]+).*)|<li><a href="\1">\2</a></li>|' file.txt
```

And I'd like to perform more substitutions, but only on the `\2` backreference, not the whole line. Is that possible, and how?

Comment: I don't think so. Use `perl` so you can get the backreference in a variable and process it before substituting.

Comment: But maybe if you show examples of what you want to do, there's a way by refining the regular expression to get the parts of `\2` into different backreferences.

Comment: it's possibe but you have to re-select the group in following substitution or extract it and reinject it later (using hold buffer). Give some sample. Now another tools is maybe better like awk (or perl like @Barmar suggest). It will highly depend on wanted action

Comment: Sure but don't do it - just use awk and the end result will be much simpler, clearer, more robust and possibly briefer. If you post some sample input and expected output and tag the question with awk then someone will help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With sed this can be done like so:

```
sed -r 'h; s|(.*dn=([^&]+).*)|<li><a href="\1">\n</a></li>|; x; s//\2/; s/foo/bar/; G; s/(.*)\n(.*)\n(.*)/\2\1\3/' filename
```

That is:

```
#!/bin/sed -rf

h                                                 # copy line to hold buffer

s|(.*dn=([^&]+).*)|<li><a href="\1">\n</a></li>|  # generate the outer parts of
                                                  # the wanted result, with a
                                                  # newline where \2 will go
                                                  # when it was edited

x                                                 # exchange hold buffer and
                                                  # pattern space to bring back
                                                  # the input line

s//\2/                                            # isolate \2 (// reattempts the
                                                  # previous regex)

s/foo/bar/                                        # your substitutions here

G                                                 # append hold buffer to pattern
                                                  # space

s/(.*)\n(.*)\n(.*)/\2\1\3/                        # rearrange the parts in the
                                                  # desired order.
```

Given the input

```
http://www.example.com/website.html?a=b&dn=foo&asd=fgh
```

this will generate

```
<li><a href="http://www.example.com/website.html?a=b&dn=foo&asd=fgh">bar</a></li>
```

**Side note:** Since your `\1` is the whole match, it would arguably be nicer to use `&` in the replacement of the first `s` command, i.e.

```
#                             v-- here
s|.*dn=([^&]+).*|<li><a href="&">\n</a></li>|
```

Doing so will require `s//\1/` instead of `s//\2` in the solution above, since the capturing group is now `\1`.

Comment: `s//Using \1/` will take the same search pattern as previous used, so it will go in the meanig of the question **BUT** there is a substitution between the 2 so `\1` and subsequent are not necessary the same (nor corresponding pattern at all) because it does not take result of "s1".

Comment: @NeronLeVelu The original text is brought back to the pattern space before the second substitution, so the same things will be captured the second time the regex is applied.

Comment: `echo "hello" | sed 's/\(.\)\1/o/;s//[&]/'` return `he[oo]` not `he[ll]o` or `heo[ll]o`. second `s` is using the same pattern but with new content

Comment: sorry we are speaking of 2 different thing. You are speaking of your script (with indeed, putting back the original content, giving same search pattern AND result) and me about using s// that use same pattern but with new content. You got the point

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now. Yes, that's true. The regex is reattempted, and if the data in the pattern space changed, so do the match and captures.

Answer (score -1):

Using @Wintermute's sample input:

```
http://www.example.com/website.html?a=b&dn=foo&asd=fgh
```

and GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match() to hold the capture groups in an array:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/(.*dn=([^&]+).*)/,a) { $0="<li><a href=\"" a[1] "\">" a[2] "</a></li>"} 1' file
<li><a href="http://www.example.com/website.html?a=b&dn=foo&asd=fgh">foo</a></li>

$ awk 'match($0,/(.*dn=([^&]+).*)/,a) { sub(/foo/,"bar",a[2]); $0="<li><a href=\"" a[1] "\">" a[2] "</a></li>"} 1' file
<li><a href="http://www.example.com/website.html?a=b&dn=foo&asd=fgh">bar</a></li>
```

Just replace `sub(/foo/,"bar",a[2])` with whatever it is you really want to do with the 2nd capture group.